# SFML image.saveToFile constantly throws error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I had a couple ideas to create images, so I wanted to test out and get used to saving an image with SFML, but for some reason it always throws an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

int main() {
    // Window
        // Main Window
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(900, 600), "Conecept", Style::Default);

    Image image;
    image.create(30, 30, Color::White);
    if (!image.saveToFile("result.bmp")) printf("Error >:(\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Idk if it's what I have or if it's something to do with Visual Studio's libraries.
These are my libs:

```
sfml-graphics.lib
sfml-window.lib
sfml-system.lib
sfml-main.lib
opengl32.lib
freetype.lib
winmm.lib
gdi32.lib
```

Started throwing:

> Exception thrown at 0x60A76B9E (sfml-graphics-2.dll) in Concept4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0258F717.

Comment: Does this code really 'throw an error' (i.e. an exception is generated) or does the function fail and your error message `Error >:(` gets printed? If it really does throw then could you state any error message displayed.

Comment: Which version of SFML you are using? There is no`Colour::White` in sfml. It should be `Color::White`. After this fix, I've no issue compiling and generating the image.

Comment: @john It keeps printing the error message that I've written down.  Before, it was throwing something else, but I can't remember what it was, what I did to fix that, or how to do it again.

Comment: @ItsThatSpicymeme From the Colour/Color confusion it seems this is not the real code. And it seems the code has been through at least a couple of iterations It's vital to post code that actually generates the problem you are complaining about.

Comment: @john The Colour thing was just a mistake on my part when rewriting the code, as it's what I'm used to.  However, I can assure you this was the code that I had written.  I have now extended the project to something a little more, but when running this either with the project or just stand alone, it still throws an error of either the printf statement or now sometimes an >Exception thrown at 0x60A76B9E (sfml-graphics-2.dll) in Concept4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0258F717.

Comment: @ItsThatSpicymeme I don't see anything wrong with the code. I would guess some kind of version or build issue, but I'm just guessing. Perhaps try upgrading to the latest SFML and start again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for answers for an issue on loading images from files, I found out that I had specified the normal dynamic and dynamic + debug versions of my .libs for SFML 2, when Visual Studio should've just been using dynamic + debug in debug mode (which admittedly makes sense but I would've never figured that out on my own TT)